# How to fix or query heuristic fragments in Strapi + React + Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, strapi

I'm building a site using Strapi and React. When I query the data using the graphql playground I am able to see the data that is returned, however in my frontend using apollo, I get this error:

> index.js:1 You are using the simple (heuristic) fragment matcher, but
>   your queries contain union or interface types. Apollo Client will not
>   be able to accurately map fragments. To make this error go away, use
>   the `IntrospectionFragmentMatcher` as described in the docs:
>   https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments.html#fragment-matcher

and

> index.js:1 WARNING: heuristic fragment matching going on!

the URL for the docs doesn't work and after google the error, every answer is quite out of the scope for the knowledge I have.

This is the query in my graphql playground:

```
      {
        page(id: 1) {
          slug
          id
          title
          body {
            __typename
            ... on ComponentContentText {
              id
              body
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentContentButton {
              id
              linkUrl
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

here is the result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": {
      "slug": "home",
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Home",
      "body": [
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentContentText",
          "id": "1",
          "body": "# Lorem Ipsum!\n\nLorem Ipsum dolor..."
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentContentButton",
          "id": "1",
          "linkUrl": "how-it-works"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentContentButton",
          "id": "3",
          "linkUrl": "about"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentContentText",
          "id": "2",
          "body": "## Lorem Ipsum dolor"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentContentText",
          "id": "3",
          "body": "Lorem Ipsum dolor..."
        },
        {
          "__typename": "ComponentContentButton",
          "id": "2",
          "linkUrl": "contact"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my component in react:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
//import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

const Page = () => (
  <Query
    query={gql`
      {
        page(id: 1) {
          slug
          id
          title
          body {
            __typename
            ... on ComponentContentText {
              id
              body
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentContentButton {
              id
              linkUrl
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <p className='loading'>loading</p>;
      if (error) return <p className='error'>error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>;
      //return <ReactMarkdown source={data} />;
    }}
  </Query>
);

export default Page;
```

As I am quite new on this, I would like to know and understand how to return this data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about fragments in Apollo GraphQL [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/#fragments-on-unions-and-interfaces). For a newbie with Apollo GraphQL, I recommend you using `useQuery` rather than `Query` component which will not be supported in Apollo 3.0 [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/react/components/). You can read more in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61834091/react-an-component-attribute-is-not-properly-storing-the-data-from-a-query-th/61861609#61861609).